# Overlay over RelativeLayout doesn't work on images in the layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a relativeLayout with textviews and imageviews.

When I overlay the layout like this:

```
    color = new ColorDrawable(Color.argb(80, 0, 0, 0));
        mMainLayout.setBackground(color);
```

The layout has some darker color.

Except the imageviews they keep the same. So I thought I give it a try with

```
 statsImage.setImageAlpha(255);
```

But still the image keeps the same.

Can someone help me?

Someone also an explanation why the imageview doesn't get the overlay? It is a child of the layout:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/headerImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_profile_pic" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/statsImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_stats" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:

I now got this:

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/overlayMainView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />
```

And I set the background color like this:

```
color = new ColorDrawable(Color.argb(80, 0, 0, 0));
mMainViewOverlay.setBackground(color);
```

Comment: mMainLayout.setBackground(color); sets,  hmm,  a background sow how background can overlay something that is in foreground? what you need is a view that completly covers your relative layout

Comment: So I just need to add a <view> around everything and set thats background color?

Comment: i could not express it better, yes, just use an ordinary View and set its background color to semi transparent

Comment: Found the problem :). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. You need to use the code like in my edit. You just need to add the "black" view at the end of the relative layout otherwise all the things you add after the view lay on top off the view.